# Title not updating in nextjs, tailwind css app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Basically, the title of my website won't update even when I am using next/Head, and have the title tag included.

```
"use client";
import Head from 'next/head';

import { BsFillMoonStarsFill } from 'react-icons/bs'
import {AiFillTwitterCircle, AiFillLinkedin, AiFillInstagram, AiFillGithub} from 'react-icons/ai'
import Image from "next/image";
import intro from "../public/intro.png";
import { useState } from 'react';
import design from "../public/design.png"


export default function Home() {
  const[darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false); 
  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? "dark": ""}>
      <Head>
        <title>{"Alexander Zhao"}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favion.ico" />
      </Head>
       <main></main>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From docs](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-3)

> In Next.js 13.2, we announced a new Metadata API, allowing you to
> define metadata (e.g. title, meta, and link tags inside your HTML head
> element) by exporting a Metadata object from a layout or page.

```
// this is for typescript
import type { Metadata } from 'next'

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Alexander Zhao",
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work still, am starting to think the problem is with the build of my app.

Comment: I have the same issue. Behavior is similar and I'm using "metadata" titles. Once i click, I see the old Title, then I refresh and it changes.

Comment: @JulioChamizo are u in a server component